# Video works well in Unity Editor but NOT in Android phone (Unity APK)

Tags: unity-game-engine, apk, unity-editor

After I build my app into .apk file and launched in my android phone, it only show the starting sequence of the video without the video playing and no sound. It works well in Unity Editor but not in my phone. I did set the minimum API Level to API level 24 before building the app, to ensure that the app is compatible with devices running Android version 7.0 (Nougat) or higher. The 3D object I used is 'Plane'.

I did tried to reinstalled the app and surfed around the internet for solutions to no avail. Why does it works well in Unity Editor but not in my phone.

Comment: id guess it doesnt have the license/encreyption/whatever its called to play it.

Comment: What codes are used by the Video (video and audio)? What test device(s) do you use?May be the video uses an audio codec not supported by the device.